# jQuery jScrollPane does not work on <div> when <p> given height value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got a div containing two p elements. jScrollPane works fine when no css is applied to the p elements but I want to give these two different max-height values. As soon as I do this the jScrollPane fills up the whole side bar and won't scroll. I've finally realised this is the problem but have no idea how to fix it.

The standard scroll bar still works with max-height set.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- the jScrollPane script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

<!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".outer").jScrollPane();

});
</script>
<link href="style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="jscrollpane.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    


</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">

<p class="p1">Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
Humpty Dumpty had a big fall
All the king's horses
And all the king's men
Couldn't put Humpty together again
    </p>

<p class="p2">Can Humpty Dumpty recover for his injuries considering the fact that he had a skull as 
thin as an egg shell, which is not normal for human beings? Yes! The law of personal injury 
in a nutshell (not to be confused with egg shell) makes persons who are negligent, liable 
for injuries that they cause that are reasonably foreseeable. The case law on the subject 
has concluded that it is reasonably foreseeable that persons who are injured may have 
pre-existing conditions, or deformities, and that a negligent person must take the injured 
person as they find them. Hence Humpty Dumpty is entitled to a recovery eventhough is head 
is as thin as an egg shell.
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS...

```
   .outer {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .p1 {
        max-height: 75px;
    }

    .p2 {
        max-height: 105px;
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Would you create a jsFiddle for this.

Comment: @Jolly Oli why you wana give the height to both `<p>` elements?

Comment: Stephen, I'm failing at jsFiddle too, this is it but I don't think jQuery is loading for some reason. I can't see what I've missed > https://jsfiddle.net/emg12waf/1/

Comment: Shehary, eventually I want to hide p2 and only have it appear when p1 is clicked on. p1 will never overflow whereas p2 might. I want the combined height of the two p elements to be limited.

Comment: @JollyOli add `padding:1px;` to `outer` css selector and see if scroll moves up and down

Comment: Adding padding didn't make any difference, your answer did work though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Pure CSS approach it's not possible but with JS you can achieve what you mentioned in comment.

- Want to hide p2 and only have it appear when p1 is clicked on.
- p1 will never overflow whereas p2 might.
- The combined height of the two p elements to be limited.

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <p class="p1">
        Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall Humpty Dumpty had a big fall
        All the king's horses
        And all the king's men
        Couldn't put Humpty together again
    </p>

    <p class="p2">
        Can Humpty Dumpty recover for his injuries considering the fact that he had a skull as 
        thin as an egg shell, which is not normal for human beings? Yes! The law of personal injury 
        in a nutshell (not to be confused with egg shell) makes persons who are negligent, liable 
        for injuries that they cause that are reasonably foreseeable. The case law on the subject 
        has concluded that it is reasonably foreseeable that persons who are injured may have 
        pre-existing conditions, or deformities, and that a negligent person must take the injured 
        person as they find them. Hence Humpty Dumpty is entitled to a recovery eventhough is head 
        is as thin as an egg shell.
    </p>
</div>
```

Changes in CSS, remove `max-height` from both `<p>` elements

```
.outer {
   width: 250px;
}
 .p1 {

}
 .p2 {

}
```

Change JS as following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $('.outer p').height();

    $('.outer').css({'height' : height});
    $('.outer').jScrollPane({

    });
});
```

The above JS code adjust the height of the `outer` css selector according to first `<p>` element and it's dynamic, with more content adding or removing from first `<p>` element the height adjust itself and the second `<p>` element will remain hidden and only show on scroll.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyo4zr9j/2/)

Comment: Thanks Sherary. Still a bit confused why setting height of <p> messes up jscrollpane but this works perfectly and is actually a better way of doing it I think.

Comment: it's because what you are trying to achieve can't be done with CSS, in css the property has static value once define and 2nd reason `outer` selector doesn't has the height but inner elements `p` has max heights, it can be achieve with pure css if fix height assigned to `outer` selector like here http://jsfiddle.net/qyo4zr9j/4/ but lets say you add more text in `p1` so then you have to change the `outer` height so as the `p1` height so best solution is dynamic height no need to set height and height adjust itself according to cotent

Comment: p1 won't actually overflow but this solution still helps because p1 might have less content and leave an empty space, in which case it shrinks to fit. What I don't understand though is why setting the height of the inner elements broke jscrollpane.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good with explaining things, but if you look here http://jsfiddle.net/qyo4zr9j/4/ I disable the jquery and give `outer` selector height so it works without dynamic solution, so the reason `why setting the height of the inner elements broke jscrollpane` because `outer` doesn't has the height `.outer {width: 250px;}`